# Transforming a nested data frame with varying number of elements

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a data frame with a column of nested data frames with 1 or 2 columns and n rows. It looks like *df* in the sample below:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ vector:List of 3
  ..$ : chr "p1"
  ..$ : chr "p2"
  ..$ : chr "p3"
 $ lists :List of 3
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ n1: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
  .. ..$ n2: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ n1: Factor w/ 1 level "d": 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ n1: Factor w/ 1 level "e": 1
  .. ..$ n2: Factor w/ 1 level "3": 1
```

*df* can be recreated like this :

```
v <- c("p1", "p2", "p3")
l <- list(data.frame(n1 = c("a", "b"), n2 = c("1", "2")), data.frame(n1 = "d"), data.frame(n1 = "e", n2 = "3"))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(v, l))
```

I'd like to transform it to a data frame that looks like that:

```
[v] [n1] [n2]

p1  a  1

p1  b  2

p2  d  NA

p3  e  3
```

- n1 and n2 are in seperate columns
- if the data frame in row i has n rows, the vector element of row i should be repeated n times
- if there is no content in n1 or n2, there should be a NA

I've tried using tidyr::unnest but got the following error

```
 unnest(df)
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

Does anyone has a better idea how to transform the dataframe in the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will avoid by-row operations, which will be important if you have a lot of rows.

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(df$l, fill = T, id = 'row')[, v := df$v[row]][]
#   row n1 n2  v
#1:   1  a  1 p1
#2:   1  b  2 p1
#3:   2  d NA p2
#4:   3  e  3 p3
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine! One more question on this: How to use this function if there are more than 1 column v with content that should be repeated?

Comment: maybe `setDT(df); rbindlist(df$l, fill = T, id = 'row')[, c(.SD, df[row, -'l'])]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr::pmap_df`, within each row of `df`, we combine `v` and `l` into a single data frame and then combine all of the data frames into a single data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

pmap_df(df, function(v,l) {
  data.frame(v,l)
})
```

> ```
>    v n1   n2
> 1 p1  a    1
> 2 p1  b    2
> 3 p2  d <NA>
> 4 p3  e    3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `suppressWarnings` is not required. Because when you created data frames, there are factor columns, `suppressWarnings` is to suppress the warning message when combining factors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- suppressWarnings(df %>%
  mutate(v = unlist(.$v)) %>%
  unnest())
df1
#    v n1   n2
# 1 p1  a    1
# 2 p1  b    2
# 3 p2  d <NA>
# 4 p3  e    3
```